# XOR encode a multibyte string and save to MySQL field without loss

Tags: php, mysql, varchar, xor, multibyte

I'm currently using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548861/266561) to obfuscate a bit the field values in MySQL and protect it from direct dumping. It all works good and values are stored correctly, but what happens when i try to **store a multibyte string**?

Here's an example, let's try to encode the string *álex*:

```
<?
$v = xorencode('álex');
// step 1 - encode
echo $v."\n";
// step 2 - decode
echo xorencode($v);
?>
```

Works good, i see some obfuscated string first time, and then i see *álex* again. Now if i try to save it in a **VARCHAR** field in a MySQL table, and then select it - i no longer have a utf string, instead it gets returned as *gllex*.

Note, MySQL tables and fields collations are utf8_general_ci, files are UTF-8, and i `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting. Any workaround to this?

Thanks

Comment: You should be storing as binary.

Comment: XOR-ing a multibyte string will result in invalid sequences here and there.

Comment: field type BINARY? how do i pass the resulting string to the UPDATE statement?